# Picking linux-4.18.11-surface-linux-surface as source package instead of linux-image-4.18.11-surface-linux-surface

Tags: kernel, source-packages

When I run this command: `sudo apt source linux-image-$(uname -r)`
I get this error:

```
Picking linux-4.18.11-surface-linux-surface as source package instead of linux-image-4.18.11-surface-linux-surface
E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-4.18.11-surface-linux-surface
```

I've followed some other similar posts and have uncommented out all `deb-src` and `src` lines in `sources.list`, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you originally get this kernel? I can't find any on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=surface&searchon=names). What are your Ubuntu version and device model?

Comment: This is a custom kernel for surface devices made by jakeday: https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have run `sudo apt-get update` after commenting out `deb-src` lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. And you commented out the right lines. Check *Build Environment* section of [Build Your Own Kernel wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).